# How to change the file name during the download process

Tags: java, jsp

I have a file named "MyFile.doc" on my server and a jsp in the same instance. There is a redirection in the jsp like : response.sendRedirect("MyFile.doc");. When a user comes to my jsp file, I want to give the file as "MyFile_XYZT.doc". In short, it should be downloaded with an ID created dynamically.

I've searched and found something about Content-Disposition method.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How about trying to implement the solution you found and see if it works fine?

Answer (score 10):

> I've searched and found something about Content-Disposition method.

Right, that's how you tell the browser what you'd like it to do with the response, including optionally giving a suggested filename for a download.

I don't think there's any one-liner here, though. You either need to configure your server to return `MyFile.doc` with the relevant `Content-Disposition` header or, if you want to control the name with code in your JSP, you'll have to send the response yourself using [`setHeader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to set the `Content-Disposition` header. E.g.:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyFile_XYZT.doc\"");
```

...and then opening the file, reading its contents, and sending those in the response. It's not a lot of code (probably four or five lines), but it's not a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use response.setHeader like you advice, it would named all downloaded files as "MyFile_XYZT.doc" as it is written for "filename" parameter ?

Comment: @ftb: It would *suggest* to the browser that it should use that name for the content of the response you're sending. Naturally if you want to use a different name on each request, you can do that with string concatenation. The key thing here is you need to send the header, then stream out the file contents as the response. You can't send a redirect.